# OpenCV: memory corruption when align multi images

Tags: opencv, memory

I'm working on a image align problem.

I have several images(480x640 for each) taken from one camera. These images form a cylinder surface and every pair of adjusted images share several similar columns to help align all images into a panorama one.

At beginning, I assume there is no rotation or zoomin/zoomout between every pair, so I just calculate the shift vector between two images instead of tomography matrix.

My code is:

```
//Store all images into a cv::Mat vector
std::vector<cv::Mat> image = ...
//Create a result Mat and set its content using the first image
cv::Mat result = image[0];

for (int i = 1; i < image.size(); i++) {
    //calculate the shift vector(image[i]-result) based on feature points using SURF.
    //this function works correctly and matched_diff[0] is det_x, and matched_diff[1] is det_y
    std::vector<int> matched_diff= surfMatch (result,image[i]);

    //Create a new Mat with size after combination
    cv::Mat temp(image[i].rows+abs(matched_diff[1]),image[i].cols+abs(matched_diff[0]),CV_8UC3);

    // Copy old result to its new position in temp
    // Copy image[i] to its new position in temp
    // Calculate pixel value of mixed range and copy them to their positions in temp
    ...

    //store the new result and go back to the first step
    result = temp.clone();
}
```

The det_x will increase around 300px after each combination, and of course the program needs more time to finish next combination.

The code works well when I test it using two or three images.

But after combining several images correctly(around 14), the program crashed with error:

> malloc(): memory corruption: 0x0000000000cdae50 ***

I used GDB to check where the memory problem occurred but it told me the problem caused at `result = temp.clone();`.

I think the reason is after several combination, the image(Mat) has become quite large and it needs more memory to create the `temp`, which caused the memory corruption error.

My problem is, based on my understanding of OpenCV, the `temp` object will be deconstructed after every for loop. And when crashing, the next `temp` size should be 3000px*640px. So the total memory it needs is 3000*640*3Byte= 5.5Kb. (for cv::Vec3b, each pixel takes 3 8bits to store its R G B values.), but GDB says it needs far more to clone it.

Therefor, I'm really wondering if there is anything wrong of my understanding and how could I make sure whether it is the bug of myself of it is the memory issue?

Thanks!

Comment: To add a solution, write on your answer below. Do not do that in the question. Please fix this post, it's good stuff.

Comment: sorry and thanks for your comment @karlphillip

Answer (score 2):

**You might be running out of RAM memory**.

Resize the images so they are half their original size, and try again. If it fails,  decrease their size by half one more time. Repeat this process until it succeeds.

If it doesn't, the problem might be something else and you will have to share a [MCVE (Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get more help.

Comment: Thanks so much! resize the image is a good way to debug when operating with OpenCV! Finally I found it is the bug of my algorithm that causes the issue. I'm trying to solve it and will update when finished. and I will try to make a MCVE instead of a really brief structure when I ask question next time Thanks again!

Comment: No need to thank. Just up vote the answer. **;D** 
See you around.

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone share the same situation with me, I would like to update the solution I found.

I followed @karlphillip 's advice, changing the image size to 1/4 than original. Then My program runs faster and takes less memory. So it is easy for me to debug under this condition.

The memory corruption always happened when you are copying or assigning value into/on a non-exist part of memory.

In the image align problem, there are four related positions between two images.

```
-----              -----         -----                 ----- 
| A |              | A |         | B |                 | B |
---------      ---------         ---------         ---------
    | B |      | B |                 | A |         | A |
    -----      -----                 -----         -----
```

from which we can easily determine detRow and detCol should be positive or negative according to their related positions.

Then we can calculate the size of new image after combination.

However, there are actually eight more cases easy to be ignored.

You should determine the size relation between A and B. That is the new image's row/column should not be smaller than either of A and B's row/column. Or you will copy data into a position out of your Mat, which makes memory problem happen.

Comment: If it isn't a memory exhaustion issue, I have a hunch that you are declaring memory for an image and assigning it to a pointer through the `std::vector...` or `temp` declarations that is corrupted by increment. I can't tell from your post, but to look for the matching column, if you are incrementing the pointer `image` or `temp` (thereby losing the **start address** to the block of memory), you can experience hard to track down memory corruption issues. (that would make sense why `result = temp.clone()` is involved). Just a hunch. You should removed the `C` tag.